# Sum of points and rank according to points with join three tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rank

I am creating a game where I am calculating the user points on the basis of user activities. Everything working fine I got the sum of points and on the basis of points I calculated the rank. I have two columns for points calculation PointsUp (contains up points) and pointsdown (contains down points)

```
select Sum(PointsUp-PointsDown) as points
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.Id = t1.id
where t1.ActivityTime BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
Group By t1.Id
order by points desc
```

Everything is fine but the problem come when I have to rank the users with same points then I have to consider the registeration date of user who register first will come up on ranking. The registeration date is in another table table3 i have tried to join third table but the sum is behaving odd showing wrong sum calculation

Can anyone help, please?